# Powerful WYSIWYG editor with upload image capability

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Can any one please recommend a powerful WYSIWYG (commercial/open
source) editor  which has a image upload capability.Which iam planning to use for my publishing platform.

I have been looking for it since morning but could not able to find
it.

I found CKeditor+CKFinder , but CKFinder is not available in  django/
python language. I tried to port to django but encountered several
problems.

Answer (score 3):

CKeditor is probably your best bet. It should be possible to sort out your problems with the help of the author, the Django people and stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

Comment: you can't upload images to your server via TinyMCE

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a working TinyMCE in Django but you can start integrating (F)CKEditor* with [this django plugin](http://code.google.com/p/django-fckconnector/) - probably a liitle outdated but it should be a good start.

*)CKEditor is the new name of FCKeditor.

Answer (score 1):

How about django-filebrowser + TinyMCE (I've never tried it with CKEditor)

http://code.google.com/p/django-filebrowser/

Works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Froala a lot lately (see https://editor.froala.com/). It's not free for commercial projects, but it's not expensive and really, really nice.

It has a Django package too:
https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor

For other options, please check: 
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/